What are the exact known circumstances of the disappearance of "Miletiy Zykov"?
Miletiy Alexandrovich Zykov was an obscure Soviet journalist and propagandist who became a prominent figure in the Vlasov movement during World War II.
In June 1944, he reportedly disappeared under mysterious circumstances in a village near Berlin. Some sources suggest he was reportedly abducted and possibly killed by German intelligence services.

What are the exact known Circumstances of the Disappearance of Milet
Zykov?


@njuffa My source is the russian wiki. I don't really have access to that book. Can you provide the relevant excerpts from that book or any primary source that is cited in it, along with some comments related to its reliability?
